# how to read url .txt files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem reading files using pandas (`read_csv`). I can do it using the built in, `with open(...)`, however it is much easier with pandas. I just need to read the data (numbers) between the `----`. This is the [LINK](http://meteosearch.meteo.gr/data/krieza/2020-06.txt) with one of my data url. There are more depending on the date that i insert. A sample of this is :

```
                   MONTHLY CLIMATOLOGICAL SUMMARY for JUN. 2020

NAME: Krieza Evias   CITY: Krieza Evias   STATE:  
ELEV:   119 m  LAT:  38° 24' 00" N  LONG:  24° 18' 00" E

                   TEMPERATURE (°C), RAIN  (mm), WIND SPEED (km/hr)

                                      HEAT  COOL        AVG
    MEAN                              DEG   DEG         WIND                 DOM
DAY TEMP  HIGH   TIME   LOW    TIME   DAYS  DAYS  RAIN  SPEED HIGH   TIME    DIR
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  18.2  22.4   10:20  13.5   23:50   1.0   0.9   0.0   4.5  33.8   12:30     E
 2  17.6  22.3   15:00  10.8    4:10   2.0   1.3   0.0   4.5  30.6   15:20     E
 3  18.1  21.9   12:20  14.1    3:40   1.3   1.1   1.0   4.2  24.1   14:40     E
```

Keep in mind that i cannot just use `skiprows=8` and `skipfooter=9` to get the data between the `--------`, because not all files of this format have a specific number of footer (`skipfooter`)or title (`skiprows`) to skip. Some have 2 or 3 and some others have 8-9 lines of footer or title to skip. But every file has 2 lines of `--------` where the data are between them.

Comment: I couldn't quit understand your question. read_csv() from pandas can only read csv files and as I see your file is not comma separated. Maybe it's a tab separated value. In that case use read_csv(fpath, sep='\t') or read_table(). There are more ways to read a file in pandas. BTW I think you need some string preprocessing.

Comment: yeah i know , but i can read `.txt` files also using `read_csv`. for separated value usually i use `\s+` which is any space. Do you know any better way to read files like this? i didn't find any better read command from pandas... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't directly use `read_csv` but you could do this:

```
import urllib
from io import StringIO

count = 0
txt=""
data = urllib.request.urlopen(LINK)
for line in data:
    if "---" in line.decode('windows-1252'):
        count+=1
    
    elif count==1:
        txt+=line.decode('windows-1252')
    else:
        break
    
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", header=None)
```

header is None because in your link column names are not in a row only but divided into multiple rows. If they're fixed I suggest you to put them by hand such as `["DAY", "MEAN TEMP", ...]`.

Comment: The result of txt is empty. The '---' in the judgment string is not judged correctly, and the loop processing is `break`, not `pass`.

Comment: It works for me with that link... maybe I didn't understand the format anyway.